# How to find prime factorization of number using loop?

Tags: java, loops, variables, printing

I'm supposed to find the prime factorization of this number: 600851475.

Prime factorization, according to my teacher and this website, http://www.mathsisfun.com/prime-factorization.html, are prime numbers that multiplied give you that number. So for example 12, even though its factors are 2,3,4,6, the prime factors WON'T be just 2 & 3, but 2,2,3.

I have the algorithm  to find a prime factor allready, but I can't find a way to loop so that it keeps finding the rest until there are no more prime factors.

This is what i got:

```
public class primeFactors {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int d= 600851475;
int i = 2;
if (d%i!=0) {i++;}
if (d%i==0) {d=d/i;}
System.out.println(i);
}
}
```

and it prints this: 3.

If i copy paste it multiple times it does print different things:

```
public class primeFactors {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int d= 600851475;
int i = 2;
if (d%i!=0) {i++;}
if (d%i==0) {d=d/i;}
System.out.println(i);

if (d%i!=0) {i++;}
if (d%i==0) {d=d/i;}
System.out.println(i);

if (d%i!=0) {i++;}
if (d%i==0) {d=d/i;}
System.out.println(i);

if (d%i!=0) {i++;}
if (d%i==0) {d=d/i;}
System.out.println(i);
}
}
```

That one prints: 3, 3, 4, 5, 5.
How can I do this with loops? I tried with do while loops( do { if section} while (d>i) {print i} ), but it doesn't work. I also tried with for loop (i=2;i<=d;i++) & it doesn't work. It gives me composite numbers too.
HELP PLEASE!!

Comment: If you a list of prime numbers that multiply to n, then the term you're looking for is a "prime factorization". The prime factors of 525 are 3,5, and 7. The prime factorization of 525 is 3 * 5 * 5 * 7.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an assignment, the most I'll give you is a general direction: the easiest way to write this will be to try candidate divisors and reduce. For example:

130 - try 2, it divides, so reduce
65 - maybe there's another 2 in there? try 2 again. It doesn't divide, so move on
65 - try 3  - no. 4? no. 5? yes, it divides, so reduce. 
13 - Is there another 5 in there? no. try 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12. Okay, you're done.

So you need to try candidate divisors in a loop, and you need an inner loop to make sure you cast out any repeated factors (for example, 525  will have the prime factors 3, 5, and 7 but you still want to get rid of that second 5). That should get you on the right track.

Clearly, there will be more efficient ways to write this, but if you're stuck, start with the simplest possible thing that could work, and get that working.

Comment: I just saw the rest of your answer, sorry. I do need the duplicated 5's and stuff, because my teacher said the prime factors are all suposed to multiply to that number, like in 12: 2,2,3, because it all gives 12. I thought i could leave just the 2 and 3, but no. Do you still recommend the inner loop??

Comment: Sure, the only difference is now you're keeping track of how many 5s you've found. (maybe you're adding them to a list of factors that you're going to return, or maybe you're printing them out as you find them - either way, you have to find them, and the inner loop will do that for you).

Comment: Could you please explain to me the candidate divisor loop thing to me please?

Comment: You are looking for prime factors of some number d. Each number i less than d is a potential factor. You'll try each i, starting from 2, until i is greater than d. If i is a divisor of d, you will collect i (print it out, or add it to a list, or whatever), and divide d by i, and try i again on the new d. Notice that there is an outer loop, which increases i, and an inner loop which decreases d. Both of these are while loops, but their conditions will be quite different. You should be able to work out what those conditions will be from this description.

Comment: Another thing: you should probably try to prove to yourself that this will find all and only the prime factors. Looking for this proof might well help you understand how to write the code you need.

Comment: Thank you so much! One very last thing, the loops can't be for, just while?

Comment: While and for loops are equivalent, but in this case the while loops make more sense. Notice that you don't have a known endpoint in either loop: in the outer loop, d is changing and the inner loop repeats as many times as i divides d. I think you have everything you need to solve this problem now, so I'm going to leave you to it.

Answer (score 1):

You only need something like this (Perhaps this is not the most efficient way but it was pretty straight forward and easier to understand) :

```
int d= 600851475;

for (int i = 2 ; i < (d / 2) ; i++){
    if(isPrime(i)){
        if(d % i ==0){
            System.out.println(i + "Is a prime factor of " + d);
        }
    }
}
```

But first you will need to have this method that check if it is a prime number or not

```
public static boolean isPrime(int n){
    for(int i = 2 ; i < n ; i++){
        if(n % i == 0){
            return false; 
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you reduce d as you go, there is no need to check isPrime, since you'll remove the primes as you find them. (clearly, any composite is greater than any of its prime factors, right?)

Comment: @JonKiparsky In my method I didn't reduce `d`. But yeah, I guess this technique will do a lot of unnecessary check huh

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a for loop.

```
for (int i = 2; i <= d; i++)
{
  //implement if statement here
}
```

This should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. You need to divide each factor until it no longer divides.

```
// this will print all prime divisors for n
for (int i = 2; n != 1; i++)
{
    while (n % i == 0)
    {
        System.out.println (i);
        n /= i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more please? Also my program says  The method printf(java.lang.String, int) is undefined for the type primeFactors

Comment: Regarding the algorithm, you need to divide out numbers multiple times or (say, if 2 was a factor 3 times) you would get 2 and 4 as a factor. We know we are done when the number is 1 because no other numbers can divide it. This algorithm will always result in primes because it will exclude all small primes before getting to larger composite factors. Regarding printf, I actually meant System.out.println; printf is a different language.

Comment: As for loops, the while loop is like an if statement that executes the code in curly brackets after it over and over until its statement is no longer true. The for loop is just a while loop with an expression at the beginning and one at the end of every loop. `for (int i = 2; n != 1; i++) { do_something (); }` is the exact same as `int i = 2; while (n != 1) { do_something (); i++; }`

Comment: I tried it and it worked. I'll try to adapt it to my code somehow, for I showed my teacher my previous process.

Comment: Thanks for the loop explanation, it really helps!

Answer (score 0):

How to find the prime factorization of a number?

Here is what I tried:

```py
def p_factorization(n):
    #Finding the factors of n.
    num=[i for i in range(1,n+1) if n%i==0]
    #Finding the prime factors of n.
    #Now prime_num checks to see if any of the factors of 36 have more than two "subfactors".
    prime_num=[i for i in range(2,max(num)) if len([j for j in range(1,i+1) if i%j==0])<=2 and max(num)%i==0]
    return prime_num
#Explanation:
#The num list is self-explanatory. It finds all of the factors of the number n.
#The prime_num list comprehension is where it gets complicated:
#The i represents all of the numbers in the range of the original factors that we found, 
#then we know that a number is prime if it has two or fewer factors, hence the if condition 
#applying to the len of the factors of i, which is being iterated through. 
#For example, 4 is not a prime number because the length of the list of factors is 
#3 [1,2,4].
```

And of course, we still need max(num) to be divisible by i.

You are very welcome!